# Форма и цвет Thumb у ScrollBar'a

Tags: android, recyclerview

Всем доброго времени суток! Такая проблема, нужно установить у Thumb ScrollBar'a определенную фиксированную длину и форму как на картинке приведенной ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно:

1. Создать в `res/drawable` `xml-drawable` с нужной картинкой. Либо `shape` использовать, либо `*.png` в `<bitmap>` поместить. В первом случае выглядеть может так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="4dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="#00ff00"
        android:startColor="#ff0000"/>
    <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
</shape>
```

2. Указать созданный в `res/drawable` файл через атрибут. Например файл назван `test.xml`:

```
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/test"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```